# What is the default username and password for localhost server on my windows 8?

Tags: web, ftp, webserver, localhost

I am trying to use FTP client to upload files to my localhost server. I really need to know how to initiate connection with localhost server. Is there a default username and password for localhost server? Thanks for the much anticipated reply!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using IIS FTP server, it by default uses Windows authentication. Meaning you login using the same credentials as you login to your Windows.